# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When using blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access, objective-c-category

Have used block in SecondViewController. Created block as property and added copy attribute. But, It crashes when it reaches `**self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC(name);**`

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^didSelectImageInImagePickVC)(NSString *imageName);
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
NSString *name = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC(name);
```

**Firstviewcontroller.m**

```
__typeof(&*self) __weak weakSelfImagePick = self;

[[SecondViewController sharedInstance] setDidSelectImageInImagePickVC:^(NSString *imageName){
    NSLog(@"Image: %@", imageName);
}];
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this  setDidSelectImageInImagePickVC in question where you declared .

Comment: It is declared in SecondViewController.h

Comment: where and when did you instantiate didSelectImageInImagePickVC?

Comment: @Joshua In SecondViewController.h

Comment: @WillRock instantiate not declare. is it getting instantiated after you call secondViewController which causes the crash? because it seems that you are calling the block but self.didSelectImageINImagePickVC is nil

Comment: @Joshua Yes. self.didSelectImageINImagePickVC is nil.

Comment: it just means that you didn't set it before you call it. thats why I was asking where and when did you instantiate the block

Answer (score 0):

Try to access secondViewController's exist block as below.

in question your are created new block

```
[SecondViewController sharedInstance]. didSelectImageInImagePickVC = ^(NSString * imageName) {
        // here your image name
    };
```

**OR**

you need to assign argument block to your class's block property.

```
-(void)setDidSelectImageInImagePickVC:(yourblock)block{
   self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC = block
}
```

Comment: Have tried the 1st suggestion. Didn't work. It crashes at self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC(name);

Comment: did you assign block in secondViewController . because it is nil so.

Comment: try second solution also for assing block to your block property.

Comment: while dismissing SecondViewController, calling the block. That is where it crashes. At this line --> self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC(name);

Comment: -(void)setDidSelectImageInImagePickVC:(void (^)(NSString *))didSelectImageInImagePickVC {
    self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC = didSelectImageInImagePickVC;
}

Comment: you are dismissing secondViewController then calling the block? isn't it already deallocated? have you tried `if (self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC){self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC(name);}`

Comment: try to check block as @Joshua suggest or give different name block property .

Comment: @Joshua Have tried the block before dismissing SecondViewController. It doesn't go through the loop. The block is nil.  if (self.didSelectImageInImagePickVC){self.didSelectImageInImag‌​ePickVC(name);}